# Datetime get start and enddate of next week

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.5

I have a small calendar application where you can see all workingdays of the current week. Now I added some buttons to swap weeks on and weeks back.

```
var monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)//22.02.16
var friday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)//26.02.16
```

I want to get next monday and next friday of next week so the variable nextMonday and nextFriday should be:

```
var nextMonday = //29.02.16
var nextFriday = //04.03.16
```

Comment: Note that your code for `monday` and `friday` does not work on sundays. `(int)DayOfWeek.Sunday` is `0` and so the result is already the next monday/friday.

Comment: @RenéVogt It's correct if you consider Sunday to be the first day of the week instead of the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as using `DateTime.AddDays` to add 7 days.

```
var nextMonday = monday.AddDays(7);
var nextFriday = friday.AddDays(7);
```